# How can I join 3 columns on one table with 1 columns from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (`Table1`) with 5 columns, each result shows an ID for a timezone (`TZID`). In a seperate table (`Table2`) is a list of these IDs, with the corresponding name for them. I need to join them so as that for each column result, it shows the corresponding name for them. But I can only seem to figure out how to join for the result of 1 column. For example:

**Table1 joined with Table2**

[image]

Here I have joined `Column3` with `TZID` from `table 2`. But if `Column3` is equal to zero, and `Column 1` or `2` is not, I need `TZID` from `table2` to return that corresponding `name` from `Table2`.

Currently I have the following:

```html
SELECT 
      Column1 
     ,Column2 
  ,Column3
  ,Table2.TZID as 'TZID from Table2'
  ,Table2.[DESCRIPT] as 'Name from Table2'

  FROM Table1
  left outer join Table2 on Table2.TZID=Table1.Column3
```

I have tried using REPLACE, is it possible to replace with the reult from another table? Something like

`REPLACE(Column1, Table2.TZID, Table2.[DESCRIPT]) AS 'Column1 Mask'`

Is there any way to actually do this?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because square braces are usually associated with SQL Server.  Have you tried using your code?  `REPLACE()` should work.

Comment: REPLACE() will only a string value unfortuantely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to join with priorities, first join with Column3 if it is not 0. If Column3 is 0 then join with Column1. And if column 1 is also 0 then join with Column2, right?

If this is correct, then you need a sql query like this:

```
SELECT 
      Column1 
     ,Column2 
     ,Column3
     ,Table2.TZID as 'TZID from Table2'
     ,Table2.NAME as 'Name from Table2'

  FROM Table1
  LEFT OUTER join Table2 on Table2.TZID =
  CASE
    WHEN Table1.Column3 <> 0
       THEN  Table1.Column3
    WHEN Table1.Column1 <> 0
       THEN Table1.Column1
    WHEN Table1.Column2 <> 0
       THEN Table1.Column2
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to join all tree columns in one query, you can join one table multiple times and rename it.

```
> SELECT 
>       Column1 
>      ,Column2 
>      ,Column3
>      ,t2c1.TZID as 'TZID Column1'
>      ,t2c1.NAME as 'Name Column1'
>      ,t2c2.TZID as 'TZID Column2'
>      ,t2c2.NAME as 'Name Column2'
>      ,t2c3.TZID as 'TZID Column3'
>      ,t2c3.NAME as 'Name Column3'
> 
> FROM Table1   LEFT OUTER join Table2 t2c1 on t2c1.TZID = Table1.Column1  
>               LEFT OUTER join Table2 t2c2 on t2c2.TZID = Table1.Column2    
>               LEFT OUTER join Table2 t2c3 on t2c3.TZID = Table1.Column3
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, I need them in seperate column. Thanks tho